# Add SPE module to custom Sitecore Docker Image

Tags: powershell-extensions, docker

I am trying to add `SPE module to XP0` but getting error as shown in the image and its occurring while building the image. what am I doing wrong ?  I have tried `SPE 6.2-1809 version` as well.

```
SPE_IMAGE: ${SITECORE_MODULE_REGISTRY}spe-assets:${SPE_VERSION}  //docker-compose.override.yml   
SITECORE_MODULE_REGISTRY=scr.sitecore.com/sxp/modules/            // .env                    
SPE_VERSION=6.1.1-1809                                           //.env
```

[image]

**Docker-Compose file -**

```
cm:
    image: ${REGISTRY}${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-xp0-cm:${BUILD_VERSION}
    build:
      context: ${LOCAL_BUILD_PATH}/cm
      args:
        BASE_IMAGE:  from AWS
        TOOLING_IMAGE: ${SITECORE_TOOLS_REGISTRY}sitecore-docker-tools-assets:${TOOLS_VERSION}
        SPE_IMAGE: ${SITECORE_MODULE_REGISTRY}spe-assets:${SPE_VERSION}
        HORIZON_INTEGRATION_ASSETS: ${SITECORE_COMMUNITY_REGISTRY}modules/custom-horizon-integration-assets:10.0.1-${NANOSERVER_VERSION}
        HORIZON_ZENITH_ASSETS: ${SITECORE_COMMUNITY_REGISTRY}modules/custom-horizon-zenith-assets:10.0.1-${NANOSERVER_VERSION}
        HORIZON_INSIGHTS_ASSETS: ${SITECORE_COMMUNITY_REGISTRY}modules/custom-horizon-insights-assets:10.0.1-${NANOSERVER_VERSION}
        RAZL_CONNECTION_IMAGE: ${RAZL_CONNECTION_IMAGE}
    volumes:
      - ${LOCAL_BUILD_PATH}\cm\deploy\website:c:\deploy
      - ${LOCAL_DATA_PATH}\cm:c:\inetpub\wwwroot\App_Data\logs
      - ${LOCAL_BUILD_PATH}\cm\deploy\serialization:c:\Serialization
    environment:
      RAZL_AccessGuid: ${RAZL_ACCESS_GUID}
    entrypoint: powershell -Command "& C:\tools\entrypoints\iis\Development.ps1"
```

**Docker File -**

```
# escape=`
ARG BASE_IMAGE
ARG SXA_IMAGE
ARG SPE_IMAGE
ARG TOOLING_IMAGE
ARG HORIZON_INTEGRATION_ASSETS
ARG HORIZON_ZENITH_ASSETS
ARG HORIZON_INSIGHTS_ASSETS
ARG RAZL_CONNECTION_IMAGE
FROM ${RAZL_CONNECTION_IMAGE} as razl
FROM ${BASE_IMAGE}
FROM ${SPE_IMAGE} as spe
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]
# Copy code from deploy folder
COPY .\deploy\website C:\inetpub\wwwroot
# Copy serialization from deploy folder
COPY .\deploy\serialization C:\serialization
# Copy role transforms
COPY .\transforms\ \transforms\
# Add SPE module
COPY --from=spe C:\module\cm\content C:\inetpub\wwwroot\
# Copy Razl connector files
COPY --from=razl c:\RazlService c:\inetpub\wwwroot
# Perform role transforms
RUN C:\tools\scripts\Invoke-XdtTransform.ps1 -Path .\ -XdtPath C:\transforms

WORKDIR C:\inetpub\wwwroot
```

Comment: What is your value for `SITECORE_MODULE_REGISTRY`?   I'm guessing it doesn't point to the official Sitecore one

Comment: SITECORE_MODULE_REGISTRY=scr.sitecore.com/sxp/modules/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change your DockerFile. To this:

```
# escape=`
ARG BASE_IMAGE
ARG SXA_IMAGE
ARG SPE_IMAGE
ARG TOOLING_IMAGE
ARG HORIZON_INTEGRATION_ASSETS
ARG HORIZON_ZENITH_ASSETS
ARG HORIZON_INSIGHTS_ASSETS
ARG RAZL_CONNECTION_IMAGE
FROM ${RAZL_CONNECTION_IMAGE} as razl
FROM ${SPE_IMAGE} as spe
FROM ${BASE_IMAGE}
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; 

... etc
```

Each `FROM` command will change the "active compose context" or whatever the official term is. So `FROM ${BASE_IMAGE}` needs to be the last `FROM` statement you issue for the initial part of the build (as this is what the DockerFile expects). Then later on you switch in the additional layers you want to pull data from.

Comment: Thank you :) Image build successfully.